# axios.post() error about circular structure

Tags: node.js, axios, expo

Please guide me in case I'm not in proper use of axios.  This simple piece of code can directly run:

```
const axios = require('axios')

axios.post('https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send', {"to":["ExponentPushToken[xxxxxxx]"],"title":"test title","body":"test body."})
  .then(responseExpo => {
     console.log("expo replied normally: " + JSON.stringify(responseExpo));
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("expo replied with error: " + JSON.stringify(error,null,4));
  });
```

The result is:

```
Promise { <pending> }
expo replied with error: {}
```

"axios": "^0.19.2"

I tried to post with api tools and see a response with normal 200 status code:

```
{
  "data":[
  {
    "status": "error",
    "message": "\"ExponentPushToken[xxxxxxx]\" is not a registered push notification recipient",
    "details":{
      "error": "DeviceNotRegistered"
    }
  }
  ]
}
```

(you may ignore the "error": "DeviceNotRegistered" inside this json cos it's expected because I have put an invalid xxxxx input value when calling the api.  Even putting a valid input value the result is still returning to the catch block with empty error)

I'm expecting it to return to the then block cos the server actually response with 200 with well formatted json result.
Have I done something wrong so that the call returns to the catch block?  Cos the error is empty I have no idea what went wrong.

===============================
after jfriend's reminder I changed to directly disply the error.

console.log("expo replied with error: " + error);

it is show like this now:

```
Promise { <pending> }
expo replied with error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'ClientRequest'
    |     property 'socket' -> object with constructor 'TLSSocket'
    --- property '_httpMessage' closes the circle
```

Anyone can let me know what exactly it means and guide me how to correct my usage?

Comment: The standard error object does not have enumerable properties so it will `JSON.stringify()` as an empty object.  Instead, do this:  `console.log("expo replied with error: ", error);` to see everything in that error object.

Comment: thanks for the hints jfriend00 .   let me revise the question

Comment: That error is caused by`JSON.stringify(responseExpo)`.  You would save yourself a lot of time if you stopped trying to stringify things you send to `console.log()`.  You can just pass an object directly without stringifying it first.  Change this `console.log("expo replied normally: " + JSON.stringify(responseExpo));` to this: `console.log("expo replied normally: ", responseExpo);`

Comment: `responseExpo` contains circular references.  You can't stringify it.  You can just log it directly without stringifying it to see what it contains.

Comment: umm... is expo responding with the error?  or is it replying this message:

{
  "data":[
  {
    "status": "error",
    "message": "\"ExponentPushToken[xxxxxxx]\" is not a registered push notification recipient",
    "details":{
      "error": "DeviceNotRegistered"
    }
  }
  ]
}

but just axios consider it to be having circular structure so reject to the catch block?  ClientRequest, socket,  TLSSocket, _HttpMessage property these things are they from a response from expo or from an internal object of axios?

Comment: The axios promise was resolving and going to the `.then()` handler.  Your own code with the `JSON.stringify()` in the `.then()` handler threw an exception causing it to go to the `.catch()` handler.  All should be clear if you get rid of the two `JSON.stringify()` and just log actual objects.  It's not axios that complained about the circular structure.  That's your code with the `JSON.stringify()` that caused that.

Comment: <problem resolved>.  the reponse (responseExpo in the question) is neither a plain data JSON nor a plain string.  it is an object with 
(see https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema) some attributes.  The real response content is inside "response.data".  

I was wrongly treating the response to be a plain json object or the http response content.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(problem resolved). the response (responseExpo in the question) is neither a plain data JSON nor a plain string. it is an object with (see github.com/axios/axios#response-schema) some attributes. The real response content is inside "response.data". I was wrongly treating the response to be a plain json object or the http response content.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and as solution, I used `HttpService` from `nestjs` which returns `Observable<AxiosResponse<T>>`. I fixed the problem by piping and plucking the request like this:

```
http.put<T>(url, data, config).pipe(pluck('data'))
```

Comment: Finally found it, thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with `HttpService` from `nestjs` which returns `Observable<AxiosResponse<any>>`. I resolve with:

```
this.httpService.post(this.legacyAccessTokenEndpoint, form, { headers: form.getHeaders() }).pipe(map(x => x?.data))
```